# In jinja2 and pelican, how do I put a string with quotes into an HTML attribute?

Tags: python, jinja2, pelican

I am using Python Pelican static page generator, which uses jinja2. I am working on my own template for the page. In this template, I want to use a few schema.org `itemscope`/`itemtype` declarations.

I am having a problem with quotation marks though. I have a string that I want to put into the `about` section.

I have this in my template:

```
<meta itemprop="about" content="{{ article.summary|e }}" />
```

The HTML is being generated like this:

```
<meta itemprop="about" content="Review of "From Whence it Come", a story by Arnold" />
```

I've also tried `{{ article.summary|safe }}`, but it results in the same output HTML.

How can I properly pass the string `Review of "From Whence it Come", a story by Arnold` to my template so that the attribute it properly quoted?

Comment: That'd work, until I have something with an apostrophe. Is there a generic way so that I could use either quotes or apostrophes?

Comment: For that specific instance, you can change `content="` to `content='`, or alternatively, try `<meta itemprop="about" {{{'content':'%s'}.format(article.summary)|e|xmlattr}}>`